# iOS Objective-C UIBarButtonItem Action Not Called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *backButton;
```

It gets set like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay target:self action:@selector(goBack:)];
    backItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    UIToolbar *backToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
    backToolbar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [backToolbar setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];
    backToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:backItem, nil];
    backToolbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
    backToolbar.clipsToBounds = YES;

    self.backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backToolbar];
    self.backButton.enabled = YES;
    self.backButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

Which I would have thought would set the selector to this:

```
- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"goBack pushed");

    [self.iframeView goBack];
}
```

But `goBack pushed` is never logged out when I click the button, though the iframeView (just a UIWebView) does go to the previous page.

I've also tried setting the action like this (set right below the above code):

```
[self.backButton setTarget:self];
[self.backButton setAction:@selector(goBack:)];
```

Any ideas how I can adjust the code such that the selector is called when I push the back button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create your `backButton` from storyboard (because you declare it as an IBOutlet)?

If you already create it from storyboard then you can simply Ctrl-Left Click to drag the button into your implementation file `.m` where the `- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender` is to create the selector.

**UPDATE:**
I just noticed you said this

> But goBack pushed is never logged out when I click the button, though
>   the iframeView (just a UIWebView) does go to the previous page.

UIWebView has the `goBack` function already. So by setting

```
[self.backButton setAction:@selector(goBack:)];
```

When the button is pressed it will called the `goBack` function of the UIWebView.

All you have to is give it a different name:

```
[self.backButton setAction:@selector(backButtonPressed:)];

- (IBAction)backButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"goBack pushed");

    [self.iframeView goBack];
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's generated programmatically

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and I found a line of code is missing which is why the selector goBack: is not triggered. If I am not wrong the button "Play" is not visible when you compile

`self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.backButton;`

As I observed you have created the bar button, toolbar programmatically, also you don't need the `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *backButton;` if your not using it else where in the code or you have to omit the `IBOutlet`.

Hope these helps.